# Django with PostgreSQL IntegerRangeField keeping sequential

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, linked-list

I have the following tables:
person and tiered_princing

the column passenger in tiered_pricing must be sequential and must not overlap at any time. whether you are creating, updating, or deleting a price.

***person query:***

```
SELECT * FROM person;
```

output:

```
+----+--------+--+
| id |  name  |  |
+----+--------+--+
|  1 | adults |  |
+----+--------+--+
```

***tiered_pricing query:***

```
SELECT * FROM tiered_pricing WHERE person_type_id=1;
```

output:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| pk | person_type_id(FK) | passengers(int4range) | price(decimal) |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| 20 |                  1 | [1, 1]               |             70 |
| 21 |                  1 | [2, 4]               |             60 |
| 22 |                  1 | [2, 4]               |             40 |
| 23 |                  1 | [5, 10]              |             30 |
| 24 |                  1 | [11, infinity]       |             15 |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
```

If you created a new price with range [14, Infinity]
after query the tiered_pricing table again you should be able to get the following

```
SELECT * FROM tiered_pricing WHERE person_type_id=1;
```

output:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| pk | person_type_id(FK) | passenger(int4range) | price(decimal) |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| 20 |                  1 | [1, 1]               |             70 |
| 21 |                  1 | [2, 4]               |             60 |
| 22 |                  1 | [2, 4]               |             40 |
| 23 |                  1 | [5, 10]              |             30 |
| 24 |                  1 | [11, 13]             |             15 |
| 25 |                  1 | [14, infinity]       |             10 |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
```

If you update a price with pk=22 change passenger range from [2, 4] to [2, 8]
getting:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| pk | person_type_id(FK) | passenger(int4range) | price(decimal) |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| 20 |                  1 | [1, 1]               |             70 |
| 21 |                  1 | [2, 8]               |             60 |
| 22 |                  1 | [9, 9]               |             40 |
| 23 |                  1 | [10, 10]             |             30 |
| 24 |                  1 | [11, 13]             |             15 |
| 25 |                  1 | [14, infinity]       |             10 |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
```

If delete the price with pk=21 I should get:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| pk | person_type_id(FK) | passenger(int4range) | price(decimal) |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
| 20 |                  1 | [1, 1]               |             70 |
| 22 |                  1 | [2, 9]               |             40 |
| 23 |                  1 | [10, 10]             |             30 |
| 24 |                  1 | [11, 13]             |             15 |
| 25 |                  1 | [14, infinity]       |             10 |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+----------------+
```

**Notice: I am using Django with PostgreSQL, so any suggestion using code when saving models is acceptable.**

Comment: Although I don't have a solution, here are a few points you should consider: **Firstly** "_must be ordered and sequential_" this point is not practical, if you want to display something in some order the logical conclusion is to use an order by clause. **Secondly** your update strategy is flawed, what happens then when you update some entry and it overlaps _multiple_ entries and there is no other range left to set these other entries to? **Thirdly** ideally this kind of tier based pricing should be left to a person updating the complete price system at the same time.

Comment: Hello @AbdulAzizBarkat, **in point 1** you are right is the only sequential, **about point 2**: that's why I'm asking this question, what to do when you change a range that is overlap with others. And finally, if I let one person create the price levels, couldn't that person make a mistake when creating each range? **Could you give more details on how to implement your point number 3?**